# Facebook API v1.0 vs v2.0 login causing auto migration?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is the following true? 
If you have a facebook app that is still using v1.0 of the API and a user logs in using v2.0 of the API and makes a request to /me/friends - the app with then ALWAYS return v2.0 of that route from then on (just the user's friends that also use the app), even if a new user logs in after using v1.0 of the API.

In other words, can a facebook app be automatically bumped permanently to
    v2.0 of the API by user interactions?

Comment: I doubt that. If a user logs in using v1 for the first time, then that “sticks”. However, since API v1 will only be around until end of April 2015, starting to think about stuff like that now seems quite moot. You should rather be focusing on getting everything v2 compliant by then.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'sticks'? In my case the user logged in for the first time using v2.0, and now I no longer have access to the v1.0 API. I agree with your migration suggestion, but this is still relevant for a few more weeks.

Comment: For example, for a user that logged in via v1 the first time, you will still get their global user id, even when using v2 later on. When they logged in to your app for the first time ever using v2 however, you won’t be able to get their full friend list. This should however not affect other users who logged in using v1 already, as long as your API call itself is using v1.